# AutoHotKey - "Continue" and "Cancel" Buttons

Tags: user-interface, button, autohotkey

I am a newbie with AutoHotKey, and to this point I consider myself fortunate to have created a script to automate about 90% of the data entry in a window.  I'm now trying to kick it up a notch and add a warning/caution GUI to my data entry script.  I want to pause the running script and open a GUI that will alert me to look at what has already been entered, with one button to allow things to proceed if a particular entry looks OK, and another to dump out of both the GUI and the remainder of the script if the entry is incorrect.

Here's some code I came up with, mixed with some pseudocode to help show what I want to do.

`(Previous data entry script executes to this point)

Stop the script

Gui, New

Gui, Add, Text, 'n Check Authorization Number to be sure it is A1234 (FY 15).  ; Wraps text

Gui, Add, Button, Default, Continue

Gui, Add, Button, Quit

Gui, Show, IMPORTANT!

If Continue button is clicked

----Continue with script

If Abort button is clicked

----Close the GUI

----Exit the entire script
(Resume where I left off with rest of the data entry script)`

I've read the AHK Help file and am stumped about how to make these buttons work, as well as how to properly return from the GUI back to the script if I hit continue, or quit the whole thing if I spot a problem.  I can tweak things like the size of the GUI and the button placement; what's most important is getting the GUI code right.  Can someone help with the code?  (The last programming class I took was in 2003, so I have forgotten a whole lot!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case, a GUI would be overkill. AHK (and many other languages at that) provide standard dialogs for simple user interaction called **message boxes**.
[Message boxes in AHK](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm) can be displayed in two ways:

1. `MsgBox, This is a simple message. Please click "OK".`
2. `` MsgBox, 4, Attention, Here`, you can choose between "Yes" and "No". ``

In the second case, we declared an option which controls the buttons that are displayed. You can use [`IfMsgBox`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/IfMsgBox.htm) in order to detect what the user has clicked:

```
IfMsgBox, Yes
    MsgBox, 4, Really?, Did you really mean "Yes"?
```

Putting these pieces together, we can ask the user to decide if they want to continue, without the need to create a GUI, in a few lines:

```
; Option "1" is "OK/Cancel"
MsgBox, 1, IMPORTANT!,  Check Authorization Number to be sure it is A1234 (FY 15).
IfMsgBox, Cancel
{
    ExitApp
}
; do stuff
```

This code addresses each of your other problems, too:
A message box halts the current thread until the user dismisses the dialog or it times out (if you specifically declared a timeout).
To completely stop the execution of our script, we use `ExitApp`.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try this later today and let you know how that works out.

Comment: I've been enjoying your literate AHK answers. +1. :)